# Can't clear Quartz 2D shadow

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I have a subclass of NSScrollview that needs a drop shadow. The scrollview appears and disappears based on user interaction. When the NSScrollView appears it gets shown with the shadow, that's great. However when I hide the view the shadow refuses to hide/clear.

This is the code for the NSScrollView subclass:

```
-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
CGContextRef currentContext = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];

NSBezierPath *newClipPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: NSInsetRect( [self bounds], -10, -10)];
[newClipPath setClip];

if (!self.isShadowRendered) {
    DrawShadow(currentContext, self.frame);

    self.isShadowRendered = YES;
} else {
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    CGContextClearRect([[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort],self.frame);
    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
}
}

- (void)setHidden:(BOOL)flag {
  [super setHidden:flag];

   if (!flag) {
       self.isShadowRendered = NO;        
   }
}

void DrawShadow (CGContextRef myContext, CGRect frame) {
CGSize myShadowOffset = CGSizeMake (0,  0);

CGContextSaveGState(myContext);

CGContextSetShadow (myContext, myShadowOffset, 10);

CGContextFillRect (myContext, CGRectMake (0, 0 , frame.size.width, frame.size.height));

CGContextRestoreGState(myContext);
}
```

How can I get the shadow to disappear along with the view?

Comment: [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];

Comment: Thanks @ElTomato I forgot to mention that. I am calling setNeedsDisplay: YES from the view that holds the NSScrollView. No success.